# Does "string" = "string" cost more memory

Tags: c#, .net, string, memory

As part of the refactor I make to this code, I've come across this snippet of code and I'm debating what's more correct / efficient?

**Before**:

```
string CutHeadAndTail(string pattern)
{
    if (pattern[0] == '*')
    {
        pattern = pattern.Substring(1);
    }
    if (pattern[pattern.Length - 1] == '*')
    {
        pattern = pattern.Substring(0, pattern.Length - 1);
    }
    return pattern;
}
```

**After**:

```
private string RemoveAllowedAstrisks(string pattern)
{
    pattern = pattern[0] == '*'?pattern.Substring(1): pattern;
    pattern = pattern[pattern.Length - 1] == '*' ? pattern.Substring(0, pattern.Length - 1) : pattern;

    return pattern;
}
```

What's better?
I am thinking about the line  `pattern = pattern[0] == '*'?pattern.Substring(1): pattern;`
Means, from readability point of view I prefer the second. But in the other hand, the meaning of this expression is the below two options:

1. `pattern[0]=='*'` --> in such case pattern will changed to `pattern.Substring(1)`
2. `else` --> `pattern = pattern`

While if I will choose the first way (ignoring the naming etc.) I have just the first option:

1. ```
   if (pattern[0] == '*')
   {
      pattern = pattern.Substring(1);
   }
   ```
2. ```
   return pattern;
   ```

The bottom line: Does the line `pattern = pattern` cost more memory?

Comment: It [probably doesn't matter](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/)

Comment: 1. it doesn't matter as Hans pointed out. 2. `string` is a reference type, so `pattern = pattern` does exactly nothing (well I'm not sure about the translation to IL and machine code, if that's not well optimized the reference maybe copied around from memory to cpu-registers and back to the same memory location again)

Comment: I don't worry about the performance but I'd like to know if there is an actually difference?

Comment: @Roni simplest way to check the difference is to look at the IL.  Use LinqPad or a similar tool

Comment: the big difference is that the original code is clear and readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the generated IL code to see what is created.

```
IL_000e: ldloc.0      // hello
IL_000f: ldc.i4.0     
IL_0010: callvirt     instance char [mscorlib]System.String::get_Chars(int32)
IL_0015: ldc.i4.s     42 // 0x2a
IL_0017: beq.s        IL_001c
IL_0019: ldloc.0      // hello
IL_001a: br.s         IL_0023
IL_001c: ldloc.0      // hello
IL_001d: ldc.i4.1     
IL_001e: callvirt     instance string [mscorlib]System.String::Substring(int32)
IL_0023: stloc.0      // hello
```

As you can see, the `ldloc.0` is exectued in case the `:` branch of the logical statement is run (`IL_0019`). Right after that the code jumps to `IL_0023` which executes the `stloc.0`.

This could be an issue with value types, but `string` is a reference type and such assignment does not affect the memory at all. To prove it, I have created a big string and run a few `value = value` assignments. The heap size never changed.

```
string hello = new string('a', 3202340);
hello = hello;
hello = hello;
```

[image: Heap sizes]

Answer (score 1):

If you will allow trimming ALL `*` characters from the beginning and end of the string (like `"**some string**"`), then you can just do:

```
private string RemoveAllowedAstrisks(string pattern)
{
    return pattern?.Trim('*');
}
```

Comment: This slightly changes the contract of the original method, though. `RemoveAllowedAstrisks("**foo**")` would result in `"*foo*"` in the original and `"foo"` in this version.

Comment: Thats should be an actually  bug

Answer (score 0):

Probably best way to do this is [via a regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...
private static Regex leadingTrailingAsterisks = new Regex("(^\\*)|(\\*$)");
private static string RemoveAllowedAsterisks(string pattern)
{
    return leadingTrailingAsterisks.Replace(pattern, "");
}
```

Comment: OP seems worried about _memory_ usage, not speed. I guess the `Regex` instance will need more memory than the current solution.

Comment: Using a regex in place of a couple of basic string manipulation calls is almost always massive overkill.

Comment: That's why the regex is statically initialized outside the method, it's a 1-time cost.

Comment: He is asking about memory and performance, for smaller phrases and being compiled, this would be overkill.

Comment: If you care about allocating the string twice because of memory costs, then the regex does a 1-stop replacement

Comment: Even if it's created only once, it's once more than in the current solution.

Comment: Theoretically if you were parsing a 2048-character-long string, the first method would allocate 2047 bytes, then 2046 bytes. Plus, compiled regex objects have really small overheads.

If you're not working with really big strings, then, [it 100% literally doesn't matter](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the first way because it is more simple and makes it easier for the compiler to make any optimizations.

To be truthful, I don't know if the compiler will optimize away `pattern = pattern` in the second approach. It might. Only speed tests will help you determine that.

Personally, I find the second approach more terse but not more readable. And I wouldn't write code that assigns a variable to itself if I didn't need to do that.

A more readable way would be to use `string.Trim()`, but I would consider that less efficient.

Comment: Absolutely agreed, but the Trim() option could not be solution because it breaks the previous behavior.

Comment: @Roni: Yes, it's not exactly the same logic. For example, if the string starts with multiple asterisks (`*`), it would remove all of them where your code only removes the first.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following: calculate whether to trim a character from either front or back or both, and if so, return a substring, otherwise return the string itself.

```
string CutHeadAndTail(string pattern)
{
    var s = pattern[0] == '*' ? 1 : 0;
    var e = pattern[pattern.Length - 1] == '*' ? 1 : 0;
    return (s > 0 || e > 0) ?
        pattern.Substring(s, pattern.Length - s - e) :
        pattern;
}
```